# How do I show ItemStatus in UI Spy?

Tags: ui-automation, ui-spy

How do I show the [ItemStatus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.automationproperties.itemstatus%28VS.100%29.aspx) property of an [AutomationElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.automationelement.aspx) in [UI Spy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms727247.aspx)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With UI Spy open

1. From the **View menu**
2. Click **Configure Properties**
3. Expand **AutomationElement**
4. Expand **Misc**
5. Check **ItemStatus**